# Homebrew clang can't find C standard library headers

Tags: c++, macos, clang, homebrew

I installed clang with Homebrew. If I try to compile a hello world program, I get this error:

```
In file included from hello.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:38:
In file included from /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:215:
In file included from /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:96:
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/wchar.h:119:15: fatal error: 'wchar.h' file not found
#include_next <wchar.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Clang is able to find the bundled C++ standard library headers but not the C standard library headers. GCC-8 (also installed with Homebrew) is able to find the C standard library headers. I have Xcode installed and Apple Clang can find the C standard library headers too. Maybe this has something to do with the fact that LLVM is keg-only.

Is there a one-time fix for this so that I don't have to pass a path to every invocation of clang? Maybe this is a problem with the Homebrew formula?

Comment: In C++, its <cwchar> as I see on cppreference. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/

Comment: @Hemil The error message I've shown is from **inside cwchar**. The C++ header #includes the C header but the problem is that the C header is not found.

Comment: I don't have Mac OS but this code: `#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cwchar>

int main(){
 wchar_t a[80], b[80];
 wcscpy (a, L"Hello");
 wcscpy (b, L" World");

 std::wcout << wcscat(a, b) << "\n";
}` works fine on my Fedora 29 with clang 7.0.1

Comment: @Hemil My problem is not with clang. My problem is with clang installed with Homebrew on macOS. The fact that clang works elsewhere is irrelevant.